# Creating an Object Matrix in Blender 2.82

Tags: modeling

To create an array of object in C4D, I would select the object, select a modifier, and enter the number of objects needed in the X, Y, and Z directions. Is there a similar method in Blender? Using the Matrix Modifier works but is not that simple.

Comment: did you test the "mirror" or "array" modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

To get something that looks like this;

[image]

You can use a modifier stack that looks like this;

[image]

An array only goes in one direction at a time.